# Is there a way of splitting a video into images that is supported on Mono?

Tags: c#, image-processing, video, mono, aforge

I have a requirement of splitting a video into a series of frames (images) that must work on both Windows and Mac systems (using Mono). Originally I developed this for Windows using AForge.Net but unfortunately it looks like Mono does not support AForge.Net.

The error I get when running this on Mono is

```
AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll contains native code that cannot be executed by Mono
in modules loaded from byte arrays. The assembly was probably created using C++/CLI.
```

So my question is if anyone knew of a similar framework to AForge that can split videos into images that is supported on Mono as well.

Comment: AForge uses their own ffmpeg wrapper via their own Win32 native lib, so it is AForge that does not support Mono, many of their other libraries do. Checkout  https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen.git It provides a C# wrapper around the ffmpeg native library (win/osx/linux), the sample program shows the frame extraction process @ https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/blob/master/FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example/Program.cs

Comment: Hey @RobertN thanks for your response! The sample program works as expected in the given standalone solution, but I have to integrate it as a DLL into my application. I compiled the standalone solution and got the FFmpeg.AutoGen.dll and imported & referenced that into my project and used the sample program code in my application. However, doing this doesn't work and it basically does nothing. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry no idea, without debugging myself....